# set MTU in C programmatically

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, mtu

A client requested that the MTU limit should be 1492.

Is there a way to do it in the source code (program in C)?

Is there any other way to do it in general? (ifconfig?)

Why does somebody needs to modify MTU to a certain limit? What is the benefit? And the most
important: By changing the MTU is there any risk to break the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about speed directly; By increasing MTU you're reducing overhead, which is data that is responsible for the proper delivery of the package but it's not usable by the end user; This can have a increase in speed but only for heavy traffic;

Also, if you increase MTU, you're prone to increase the number of packets that are dropped (since you have a fixed bit error probability and more bits in a packet), eventually causing a decrease in performance with resent packets, etc... So it's a compromise between overhead and data integrity;

I guess that it is more of a interface configuration than something you control with a program; So it's better to stick with 'ifconfig' command or find the equivalent solution for Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to set it through programming?  Is there an API to set the MTU of a connection or interface?

Comment: I do believe it's ~possible~, but not really sure how. Problably something very platform specific...

Answer (score 7):

Programmaticaly way using C:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
struct ifreq ifr;
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "eth0");
if(!ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFMTU, &ifr)) {
  ifr.ifr_mtu // Contains current mtu value
}
ifr.ifr_mtu = ... // Change value if it needed
if(!ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFMTU, &ifr)) {
  // Mtu changed successfully
}
```

It works at least on Ubuntu, see [`man netdevice`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html).

Comment: Cool.  `ioctl()` function is also available in Windows using `Ws2_32.lib`, `Ws2_32.dll` and `winsock2.h`

Answer (score 3):

The [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) is a number which defines the maximum transmission unit per packet. The bigger it is, the faster your data will be sent. Assuming you can send `n`packets/s of `m`size, if `m` grows, `m*n` grows too.

I think your client wants that MTU because of its network equipment (maybe ethernet 802.3). Some equipment handel biggest frames size than others.

You can use [ifconfig](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ifconfig.html#tools-ifconfig-mtu) with the option `mtu`to change its value: `ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492`.

Comment: so, is it only a matter of speed and configuration (ethernet,pppoE etc)? Is there a risk to break the existing code?

Comment: as far as I know, it is more and hardware configuration issue than a software one.

Comment: On Windows in order to achieve the maximum performance it is recommended to use MTU <= 1024.

Answer (score 1):

the modern way to set interface parameters is via sysfs

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1492 > /sys/class/net/tun/mtu'
```

By C, just open and write as files